# What locations allow barging of cars into the water?

Tags: blur

In the Crash and Burn rounds, one of 'Drayke's Demands' is: "Barge 1 car into the water".

What race tracks allows barging of a car into the water, and at which point of that/those track(s) can I do that? Also, is it better to do this in a certain type of race?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LA Docks tracks (Cargo Run and Pacific Reach) are good for barging in to water, each contain at least one section where the track runs right next to the water with no barrier in between. You'd probably want to avoid Destruction races (as you wouldn't get any barges) and One-on-One races (not enough barging opportunities).

Comment: You need the barge-in-water goal to unlock the  One-on-One race, so it's not possible to unlock it in there regardless of barging opportunities :)